# How to get index of 2d list after finding maximum value from list items

Tags: python, list, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a 2d list. where I am finding the maximum value by comparing a11 with b11 and c11 and so on. For example,

```
[[2,3,4,5],[3,4,1,6],[7,1,2,10]]
```

The output is like:

```
[[7,4,4,10]]
```

Now I want the index of each the maximum value as: `[[c11,b12,a13,c14]]`

My original code is:

```
img = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("resized/*.jpg")]
X=[]
for im in img:
    arr = np.asarray(im)
    arr = np.split(arr, 20)
    arr = np.array([np.split(x, 20, 1) for x in arr])
    mat = [arr[i][j].mean() for i in range(20) for j in range(20)]
    X.append(mat)

a = max(X, key=lambda item: item[0])
```

Comment: DId you look into `np.argmax`?

Comment: I have but didn't quite understand on how to implement it here because as far I understood it finds the maximum value in the list and returns its index

Comment: Use the `axis` argument. `np.argmax(<your_nested_list>,axis=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an input of [[2,3,4,5],[3,4,1,6],[7,1,2,10]], if you are looking for the indices of [7, 4, 4, 10] (which is basically consisting of the max value of the corresponding columns of the 2D array), that can be done this way:

```
a = [[2,3,4,5],[3,4,1,6],[7,1,2,10]]
tr_a = list(zip(*a))
result = [(row.index(max(row)),index) for index, row in enumerate(tr_a)]
print(result)
```

Execution:

```
>>> a = [[2,3,4,5],[3,4,1,6],[7,1,2,10]]
>>> tr_a = list(zip(*a))
>>> result = [(row.index(max(row)),index) for index, row in enumerate(tr_a)]
>>> print(result)
[(2, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the indices of the result. By indices I mean where the element came from.

Comment: So, are you rather looking for the indices than the value itself like this: [(2,1),(1,1),(0,2),(2,3)]?

Comment: @Newbie, just updated the answer to reflect what you are looking for. Let me know. :-) Update to my above comment, it should be: [(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(2,3)]

Comment: Thanks so much that is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using numpy's `argmax()`.

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools as itt

def get_col_max_inds(arr):
    return list(zip(np.argmax(arr, axis=0), itt.count()))
```

On numpy arrays it seems to be 10 times faster than the accepted solution. I also think it's more straightforward.